# Animation based on a float value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a float value which gives me the distance between two points. I want to play a certain part of an animation for a bigger period of time if the distance is greater and for shorter if the distance is shorter. How can I increase the duration of an animation based on a value?

Comment: Which part of the question you do not understand? I think it is as precise as it can get!?

Comment: This is not a "how-to-do this with code" question. It is a question for a specific thing in Unity3D and if you have experience with it you will certainly understand.

Comment: is this in a 3d project or a 2d project?

Comment: @JRowan it's a 2D project

Comment: i guess you can make different animations for your controller and trigger them with the float, im not too sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found an answer :

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class example : MonoBehaviour {
     void Example() {
         animation["Walk"].speed = 2;
     }
 }
```